Volume distribution of charge in a wire in a DC circuit
According to this and several other articles some amount of charge in a DC circuit distributes itself on the surface of the conductor, making the electric field inside parallel to the said surface.
What I don't get is this: if you assume the interior of the wire is neutral and all electrons have the same velocity, combine that with the fact that the surface charge drops continuously along the length of the wire, you get that some surface electrons just vanish to maintain the interior neutral(since them going there would make it negatively charged). That contradicts the charge conservation law. I attached a poorly made diagram to illustrate my explanation(note that the direction of electric current is opposite to the "true" flow of charge):

My question is: is my assumption wrong(then I would like to know where surface electrons go and the overall distribution) or is it that there's a fault in my reasoning(I would like to know where it is then)? Thanks!

In electrostatics, if there is net charge in a conductor it's distributed on the surface.
While electric current flows in a wire, the wire is electrically neutral, $\rho = 0$. There are some negative free charges (conduction electrons) that can move. Positive charges can't. A current arises from the motion of the negative charges.
